# Printer Prints with some white extra spaces on header using rdlc report

Tags: c#, winforms, rdlc

I am doing **Winforms** with RDLC report. My **RDLC** **report** show white space at the Top of the report . The size is exactly same as my header.

I also set ConsumeContainerWhitespace to True , but it still not helping

> see Images

[image]

Comment: Every Bills having some of white spaces ..it is based on the printer or using paper .. set your Report Grid size as 0.010

Comment: I have done  below link https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7c6edc32-c3ab-4c13-986d-2c02832c24d9/how-to-directly-print-rdlc-report-without-showing-printdialog-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: But i am unable to avoid top empty white space.Kindly check..

Comment: It does not seem to be affected by the ConsumeContainerWhiteSpace setting being set to true or false. This is not the same issue as people who are having extra pages of white space being generated. I have tried various page sizes and settings which seem to have no effect on that white space existing.